# Add a property in realm the project is crash

Tags: objective-c, crash, realm

In follow is my realm file:

```
@property NSString *operator;
@property NSString *publishTime;
```

Now I add a property, the realm file is becoming :

```
@property NSString *operator;
@property NSString *publishTime;
@property NSString *title;
```

then I run the project in Xcode, click the button where used realm, the project is crash. The errors is

```
File "/Users/ltl/Library/Application Support/Realm/rlm_lldb.py", line 226, 
in RLMResults_SummaryProvider if not is_results_evaluated(obj):
File "/Users/ltl/Library/Application Support/Realm/rlm_lldb.py",  line 213, 
in is_results_evaluated  mode_query_value = next(m for m in mode_type.enum_members 
if m.name == 'Query').GetValueAsUnsigned()  StopIteration
```

How can I fix it ?

But When I delete the APP from iPhone, run the project again, and click the button where used realm, the project is not crash, so I have no idea how to solve this issue? God, it is crash again!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you modify the schema of a Realm object (i.e., add a new property), any existing Realm files that are using the old schema need to undergo [a migration](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#migrations) in order for them to be updated with the new property. In your case, since you're just adding a new field and not moving any data, you don't need to specify in the migration block, but it's still necessary to have:

```
RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
config.schemaVersion = 1;
config.migrationBlock = ^(RLMMigration *migration, uint64_t oldSchemaVersion) { };
[RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:config];
```

When you delete the app from the device, you're also deleting the Realm file inside it as well. When you rebuild it, you're deploying a new Realm file with the new schema, which is why it works after that.

Comment: This saved me a lot of time - it is not obvious from the docs that you have to include the migration block whether you need it or not.

Comment: Oh awesome! Thanks for that! I'm glad my answers are still providing value. Hmm, yeah? It's not worded too strongly, but the documentation does explicitly say that a migration is required if any of the objects' schema changes between launches.

Comment: I was going off the API reference for deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded, no mention there - "Whether to recreate the Realm file with the provided schema if a migration is required. This is the case when the stored schema differs from the provided schema or the stored schema version differs from the version on this configuration. Setting this property to YES deletes the file if a migration would otherwise be required or executed."